# Prevent hive from creating a reducer

Tags: hive

As per Hive's documentation, if tables T1 and T2 are bucketed and sorted by the same columns, then when we do

```
insert overwrite table T2 select * from T1;
```

should not create any reducers but just mappers.

But, I am in slightly different situation. I have columns C1 and C2 in T1 and C1 and C3 in T2.

I want to do something like this:

```
insert overwrite table T2 select C1, transform(C2) as C3 using app
```

But, as we cannot use any other column when using transform, I changed my code to

```
insert overwrite table T2 select transform(C1, C2) as (C1, C3) using app
```

But, as I do this, hive no more knows that, input and output tables are bucketed and sorted on the same column and this results in creation of a reduction step.

Is there a way to tell hive, not to create reducers but just assume that input and output tables are bucketed and sorted on the same columns?

Answer (score 0):

To tell hive to perform bucketed map join set the below in your query

```
set hive.optimize.bucketmapjoin=true;
```

To set number of reducers to zero

```
set mapreduce.job.reduces=0
```